# Execute javascript on new born DOM elements after select change

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem on new elements created after select change event.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="cont-filtri">
  <div class="form-group uno">
    <label>Marca <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label>
    <select name="brad" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="">Scegli</option>
      <option value="1">Yamaha</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group due hide">
    <label>Modello <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label>
    <select name="model" class="form-control" required disabled>
      <option value="">Scegli</option>
      <option value="1">Super bella</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group tre hide">
    <label>Anno :</label>
    <select name="year" class="form-control" disabled>
      <option value="">Scegli</option>
      <option value="1">2017</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default aggiungi-filtro"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Aggiungi filtro</button>
```

And this is my javascript :

```
$(".aggiungi-filtro").click(function(){
    $(this).before('<hr/><div class="cont-filtri"><div class="form-group uno"> <label>Marca <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label> <select name="brad" class="form-control" required> <option value="">Scegli</option> <option value="1">Yamaha</option> </select> </div><div class="form-group due hide"> <label>Modello <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label> <select name="model" class="form-control" required disabled> <option value="">Scegli</option> <option value="1">Super bella</option> </select> </div><div class="form-group tre hide"> <label>Anno :</label> <select name="year" class="form-control" disabled> <option value="">Scegli</option> <option value="1">2017</option> </select> </div></div>')
});
$(".uno select").on("change",function(){
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".due select").attr("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".due").removeClass("hide");
});
$(".due select").on("change",function(){
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".tre select").attr("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".tre").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Here is the css for hidden elements:

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

This is my fiddle:

[CLICK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/j3v3cfL8/)

I'm trying to have the same control on new born elements.

For instance, when i switch my first select option, another select shows-up and so on.

This works perfectly on my first html element, but it doesn't work on the new borns.

Can you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3v3cfL8/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also can use delegation like this too:

```
$(document).on("change", ".uno select", function(){
....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With your code, the event listener is registered only on the pre-existing select.

You can either register a new listener for the new select in the method that creates it or use a listener that is registered a the document level as already suggested in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), attaching the listener to a parent element (via JQuery selector or the document itself):

```
$(document).on("click", ".aggiungi-filtro", function(){
    $(this).before('<hr/><div class="cont-filtri"><div class="form-group uno"> <label>Marca <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label> <select name="brad" class="form-control" required> <option value="">Scegli</option> <option value="1">Yamaha</option> </select> </div><div class="form-group due hide"> <label>Modello <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label> <select name="model" class="form-control" required disabled> <option value="">Scegli</option> <option value="1">Super bella</option> </select> </div><div class="form-group tre hide"> <label>Anno :</label> <select name="year" class="form-control" disabled> <option value="">Scegli</option> <option value="1">2017</option> </select> </div></div>')
});

$(document).on("change", ".uno select", function(){
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".due select").attr("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".due").removeClass("hide");
});

$(document).on("change", ".due select", function(){
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".tre select").attr("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".tre").removeClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: Added an edition to include the usage of document, as pointed out by Himanshu, but it might be better use a selector (like '.parent-element', for a parent element, in terms of performance), as it reduces the exploration of DOM

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can avoid the event delegation because you may act differently.

I suggest you to use [clone(true)](https://api.jquery.com/clone/): Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements preserving the event handlers.

In this way you will reduce your code.

```js
$(".aggiungi-filtro").click(function () {
    $(this).before('<hr/>')
       .before($('.cont-filtri:first').clone(true)
          .find('select.form-control').val('').end()
          .find(".form-group:gt(0)").addClass("hide").end());
});
$(".uno select").on("change", function () {
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".due select").attr("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".due").removeClass("hide");
});
$(".due select").on("change", function () {
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".tre select").attr("disabled", false);
    $(this).closest(".cont-filtri").find(".tre").removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="cont-filtri">
    <div class="form-group uno">
        <label>Marca <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label>
        <select name="brad" class="form-control" required>
            <option value="">Scegli</option>
            <option value="1">Yamaha</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group due hide">
        <label>Modello <span class="mandatory">*</span>:</label>
        <select name="model" class="form-control" required disabled>
            <option value="">Scegli</option>
            <option value="1">Super bella</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group tre hide">
        <label>Anno :</label>
        <select name="year" class="form-control" disabled>
            <option value="">Scegli</option>
            <option value="1">2017</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default aggiungi-filtro"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Aggiungi
    filtro
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you but now i have dynamised the name attribut so i can't really clone all the "cont-filtri" html, but i can do this for other things ;)

Comment: also this copies the html code with already selected options, so this doesn't really fork for this problem

Comment: @LucianoMauro Regarding  your second comment I fixed the issue. You may take a look to the snippet.